# pyomo is taking forever to run

Tags: python, pyomo

Does anyone know what is wrong with my constraint or objective that makes the solver unable to solve the objective?
I need to make sure that the budget that we have for a year is enough to treat a certain asset. For some asset, they are located within the same group, so we try to move the treatment of those assets to the same year.
For each asset, it is also restricted to which year it can be moved.
I have a very limited budget but still enough for the asset to move, yet the solver does not find any solution and keep running. Following  code is executable. Looking forward to anyone that can help me with this.

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

# estimated cost for each asset
estimated_cost_dd = {0: 49327.07294, 1: 22026.18216, 2: 6613.641422, 3: 6439.077904, 4: 19092.74808, 5: 71005.47705,
                     6: 46632.3224, 7: 7238.580172, 8: 6072.856201, 9: 43138.03009, 10: 8775.922046, 11: 20366.35618,
                     12: 12138.7625, 13: 12138.7625, 14: 48251.42843, 15: 7895.688288, 16: 7972.556789, 17: 42042.41723,
                     18: 263501.5554, 19: 6433.760056, 20: 6433.760056, 21: 6547.57515, 22: 57935.37342,
                     23: 7117.017004, 24: 5682.424608, 25: 7264.794211, 26: 7264.794211, 27: 6942.685975,
                     28: 22603.94456, 29: 6486.832091, 30: 101135.4634}
# budget for each year
budget_dd = {1: 69336, 2: 430750, 3: 286106, 4: 50256, 5: 106072}
# some asset are actually the same
same_asset_dd = {'R00168': [14, 15], 'R00234': [19, 20], 'R00843': [25, 26], 'R00973': [12, 13]}
# some assets falls into the same group. for example both 12,13 are in the group 198
same_group_dd = {10.0: [0], 54.0: [1], 63.0: [2], 112.0: [3], 121.0: [4], 132.0: [5, 6], 164.0: [7], 167.0: [8],
                 171.0: [9], 178.0: [10], 185.0: [11], 198.0: [12, 13], 201.0: [14, 15], 203.0: [16], 216.0: [17],
                 220.0: [18], 240.0: [19, 20], 261.0: [21], 263.0: [22], 285.0: [23], 291.0: [24], 330.0: [25, 26],
                 346.0: [27], 347.0: [28], 350.0: [29], 381.0: [30]}
# year range of each assets that allows which year its treatment can be moved
year_range_dd ={0: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1: [1, 2, 3, 4], 2: [2, 3, 4, 5], 3: [1, 2, 3, 4], 4: [2, 3, 4, 5], 5: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 6: [2, 3, 4, 5], 7: [1, 2, 3, 4], 8: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 9: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 10: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 11: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 12: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 13: [2, 3, 4, 5], 14: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 15: [2, 3, 4, 5], 16: [1, 2, 3, 4],
 17: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 18: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 19: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 20: [2, 3, 4, 5], 21: [1, 2, 3, 4],
 22: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 23: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 24: [1, 2, 3, 4], 25: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 26: [2, 3, 4, 5],
 27: [1, 2, 3, 4], 28: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 29: [1, 2, 3, 4], 30: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
#asset with current year
current_year_dd={0: 2.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 5.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 5.0, 5: 2.0, 6: 5.0, 7: 1.0, 8: 2.0, 9: 4.0, 10: 2.0, 11: 2.0, 12: 2.0, 13: 5.0, 14: 2.0, 15: 5.0, 16: 1.0, 17: 2.0, 18: 3.0, 19: 2.0, 20: 5.0, 21: 1.0, 22: 2.0, 23: 4.0, 24: 1.0, 25: 2.0, 26: 5.0, 27: 1.0, 28: 3.0, 29: 1.0, 30: 2.0}


def initX(model, one_id, year):
    if current_year_dd[one_id]==year:
      
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
def initGroupAsset(model, one_group_ids, year):
    initialise=0
    # one in year 2 and the other in year5 for id 5 nd 6
    for n in same_group_dd[one_group_ids]:
        if current_year_dd[n]==year:
            initialise=1
    return initialise
def initSameAsset(model, one_asset_id, year):
    initialise=0
    # one in year 2 and the other in year5 for id 5 nd 6
    for n in same_asset_dd[one_asset_id]:
        if current_year_dd[n]==year:
            initialise=1
    return initialise
same_group_ids = same_group_dd.keys()
unique_id = estimated_cost_dd.keys()
total_id = len(unique_id)
year = budget_dd.keys()

same_asset_ids = same_asset_dd.keys()

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.unique_id = pyo.Set(initialize=unique_id)
model.year = pyo.Set(initialize=year)

# binary variables representing if an asset is moved somewhere
model.x = pyo.Var(model.unique_id, model.year, within=pyo.Binary, initialize=initX)
# binary variables representing if group of assets are moved somewhere
model.group_asset = pyo.Var(same_group_ids, year, within=pyo.Binary, initialize=initGroupAsset)
# binary variables representing if same assets are moved somewhere
model.same_asset = pyo.Var(same_asset_ids, year, within=pyo.Binary, initialize=initSameAsset)

model.bin_group_asset = pyo.ConstraintList()

# if any model.x[ ·, y] non-zero, model.group_asset[one_group_key, y]] must be one; else is zero to reduce the obj function
# total_id*10 is to remark, but total_id was enough since max of one year yields max of total assets, the maximum possible sum
model.bin_same_asset = pyo.ConstraintList()
for same_asset_id_key, same_asset_id_value in same_asset_dd.items():
    for y in year:
        model.bin_same_asset.add(
            expr=sum(model.x[one_id, y] for one_id in same_asset_id_value) <= model.same_asset[
                same_asset_id_key, y] * total_id * 10)

for one_group_key, one_group_value in same_group_dd.items():
    for y in year:
        model.bin_group_asset.add(
            expr=sum(model.x[one_id, y] for one_id in one_group_value) <= model.group_asset[
                one_group_key, y] * total_id * 10)
# if any model.x[ ·, y] non-zero, model.same_asset[same_asset_id_key, y]] must be one; else is zero to reduce the obj function
# total_id*10 is to remark, but total_id was enough since max of one year yields max of total assets, the maximum possible sum

model.budget_const = pyo.ConstraintList()
# Sum of estimated cost for each year should be less or equal to budget
for y in model.year:
    model.budget_const.add(
        expr=sum([model.x[one_id, y] * estimated_cost_dd[one_id] for one_id in model.unique_id]) <= budget_dd[
            y])

model.excluded_year = pyo.ConstraintList()
# make the param to be zero if outside of move range
for one_id in model.unique_id:
    inc = year_range_dd[one_id]
    exc = list(budget_dd.keys() - inc)
    for t in exc:
        model.excluded_year.add(expr=model.x[one_id, t] == 0)

#  each asset can only go to one bin (one year)
model.one_bins = pyo.ConstraintList()
for one_id in model.unique_id:
    model.one_bins.add(expr=sum(model.x[one_id, y] for y in model.year) == 1)


def group_obj(m):
    obj_1 = (sum(model.same_asset[one_asset, y] for one_asset in same_asset_dd for y in year) + 1) * len(
        unique_id) ** 3 * max(year) ** 2
    # bins is minimised for group of assets with same location.(trying to put the same location assets in the
    # same year as a many as possible)
    obj_2 = (sum(model.group_asset[one_group, y] for one_group in same_group_dd for y in year) + 1) * len(
        unique_id) ** 2 * max(year)
    # group of same assets with same id are treated as early as possible
    obj_3 = (sum(y * model.same_asset[one_ass, y] for one_ass in same_asset_dd for y in year) + 1) * len(
        unique_id) * max(year) * 5
    # group of assets with same location are treated as early as possible
    obj_4 = (sum(y * model.group_asset[group, y] for group in same_group_dd for y in year) + 1)
    return obj_1 + obj_2+obj_3 + obj_4


model.obj = pyo.Objective(rule=group_obj, sense=pyo.minimize)
engine = r'C:\Users\someone\solver\cbc.exe'
solver = 'cbc'
solver = pyo.SolverFactory(solver, executable=engine)
solver.solve(model, warmstart=True)
```

Comment: Hi, please make sure that your code example is executable for us by including all relevant imports, (un)commenting the relevant lines (and removing the spurious markdown code at the bottom). As is, your snippet looks like a puzzle to figure out which comments are needed to make your model reach the solver in one piece.

Comment: Hi sorry for that, I have pasted a new code that is executable. Looking forward to your reply soon.

Answer (score 1):

The solver is struggling to find *any* valid integer solution.*

Why?

Your total costs are: $ 942,517.86

Your budget is:       $ 942,520.00

So you have about $2 of slack in the problem and a bunch of restrictions on years that can be assigned.  **It is likely there is no feasible integer solution**.  If you plus up your budget slightly, the model solves almost instantaneously.

If you are convinced there is any feasible solution, you should consider loading that as the default to give the solver a warm start.

* How did I discover this?  Set the time limit on the solver for about 5 minutes and look at the intermediate results.

Comment: Thank you so much for you replies. 
I have intialised the value in model.X  to be the default value but it is still not working (code has been updated with new initialisation) :( . The solver should have returned a solution with the defined budget as it was the original budget before assets is moved to different year.
I have always used a large budget to find a solution which like you said works instantaneously without any issue. The reason why I used a limited budget is because those are their existing budget, so I thought it should have produced the same solutions

Comment: The initialization you provide is incomplete as you are only initializing one variable and the zeros in the others make constraints infeasible.  If you want to use a warm start, the whole thing needs to be feasible or it is tossed out by the solver as I understand.  And you need to put in the warm start option (see documentation)

Comment: Honestly though, you are wasting your time here with this budget constraint.  It is like trying to do a jigsaw puzzle in a different pattern.  In each year, you are adding up very few very large and disparate numbers (about 6) and you have 0.0002 % slack.  There will be no other fit that satisfies the yearly budget constraints.

Comment: I see. So it means that I have to set a very large budget for each year and in that case because my objective also include ensuring the total cost to be as large as the budget, it means most of my assets will only be treated in early years ?
I can think of a way to not treat my asset in early years which is by setting the budget for the earlier years to be minimum but the final years to be very large, is this a correct way to do?

Comment: Meanwhile, I have modified my code to initialise all my variable with the default value and set warmstart=True in the solver yet it doesnt give any results too, is there any more mistake? Yeah I think I might not waste my time anymore if at the end there is no solution that satifies the yearly budget and will use a larger budget to solve the problem.